# Флешки монтируется в режиме read-only

Tags: linux

Как снять защиту на запись с флешки?
Пытался вот так: `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/flash`

Пишет:

> cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected

Comment: переключатель переключть не пробовали? другие устройства монтируются нормально?

Comment: там нет переключателей, да монтируются нормально

Comment: в принципе, контроллер может и в отсутствие переключателей сообщать операционной системе, что устройство «write-protected». теоретически, у производителя может быть программа, работающая, естественно, только в ms/windows, которая способна управлять контроллером.

Comment: решение: `sudo mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/sdb2`

Answer (score 1):

> Очень часто контроллер флешки переводит её в режим read-only если считает что она «помирает». Пытается сохранить хоть какие то данные.
>   https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/13734226